Wifi connection and signal issue for Inspiron 14 5420, where I have clean installed Ubuntu 24.04
My local wifi connection is not great but not bad, I switched to Linux on my laptop and am experiencing some speed problems. The internet is very spotty and does not work well. As solution, I tried changing the network power issue from,
$ sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf  
originally the value was 3 I changed it to 2.
Then, I tried restarting, package updating, and firmware update, as it was a clean install all of it happened. Just now I tried to test for an ethernet issue, I do not have an ethernet cable, so I connected my laptop with my phone with USB Tethering to check and the speed is as expected. What is the problem and what can I do?
I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 on my Inspiron 14 5420. Any help?
